# What does the format of of the filename of keystore generated by the eth2.0-deposit-cli mean?

Tags: proof-of-stake, keystore

When I [eth2.0 deposit client](https://github.com/ethereum/eth2.0-deposit-cli), it generates the keystore file with a filename in a peculiar format. For example:

> keystore-m_12381_3600_1_0_0-1646556486.json

What exactly does this file name format means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in [the code](https://github.com/ethereum/eth2.0-deposit-cli/blob/master/staking_deposit/credentials.py#L152), the file saving lines are :

```
  filefolder = os.path.join(folder, 'keystore-%s-%i.json' % (keystore.path.replace('/', '_'), time.time()))
  keystore.save(filefolder)
```

So :

```
keystore-m_12381_3600_1_0_0-1646556486.json
```

Was generated with a `path` of `/12381/3600/1/0/0` and a timestamp of `1646556486`, it seems to be compliant with [EIP-2335](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2335) and therefore with [EIP-2334](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2334).

From EIP-2334 you can see that your path is used to traverse the tree of keys generated by deriving your mnemonic, it is defined as :

`/purpose/coin type/set of validator keys/use/{any additional path information}`

purpose is set to 12381 to identify the BLS12-381 curve that is used to generate validator keys.

For the rest, since it is specific to validator keys, you can refer to those explanations from the same EIP:

> Eth2 Specific Parameters
> Coin type The coin type used for the BLS12-381 keys in Ethereum 2 is 3600.
>
> Validator keys Each Eth2 validator has two keys, one for withdrawals
> and transfers (called the withdrawal key), and the other for
> performing their duties as a validator (henceforth referred to as the
> signing key).
>
> The path for withdrawal keys is m/12381/3600/i/0 where i indicates the
> ith set of validator keys.
>
> The path for the signing key is m/12381/3600/i/0/0 where again, i
> indicates the ith set of validator keys. Another way of phrasing this
> is that the signing key is the 0th child of the associated withdrawal
> key for that validator.

Finally, `1646556486` is nothing but a unix timestamps, meaning that this key was generated at Sunday 6 March 2022 08:48:06 (GMT).